# best way to take the id of db and then delete the file in the directory?

Tags: php, echo

I am trying to get the id of each file, then delete them all with a hidden input, I dont know If I am doing wrong, are there better ways what would be your approach??.  My code is for deleting a file first the id of the db and then the file of the folder

This is my code:

```
<?php

    include '../Model/File.php';

    $path = "uploadedfiles/";
    $directory = dir($path);
    $types = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'txt', 'gif', 'png', 'doc', 'docx', 'pdf', 'xlsx', 'pptx');
    $identifier = "";

    $objFile = new File();

    $result= $objFile->listFiles();

    foreach ($result as $array){
        $identifier = $array['name_file'];

        echo  "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"id_file\"   value=\"".$array['id_file']."\">";
        echo $array['name_file'] . "<a id=\"". urlencode($identifier)."\" href=\"#\ class=\"delete\" >Delete</a><br/>";
    }

?>
```

it outputs:

1. file1 [deletelink]
2. file2 [deletelink]
3. file3 [deletelink]
4. file4 [deletelink]

**print_r($result)**

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_archivo] => 41 [0] => 41 [nombre_archivo]
>   => 1294861647_-desktop.png [1] => 1294861647_-desktop.png [fecha] =>
>   2011-08-08 15:10:09 [2] => 2011-08-08 15:10:09 ) [1] => Array (
>   [id_archivo] => 42 [0] => 42 [nombre_archivo] =>
>   Dragon_Ball_Simpsons.jpg [1] => Dragon_Ball_Simpsons.jpg [fecha] =>
>   2011-08-08 15:11:49 [2] => 2011-08-08 15:11:49 ) [2] => Array (
>   [id_archivo] => 43 [0] => 43 [nombre_archivo] => VATOS.jpg [1] =>
>   VATOS.jpg [fecha] => 2011-08-08 16:30:00 [2] => 2011-08-08 16:30:00 )
>   )

Comment: I don't know what you are doing but you never use `$directory`

Comment: What is the 'id of a file'? inode number? full path? just filename? Since you're dealing with raw filesystem access here, be VERY careful that a malicious user can't do somethign like pass in '/etc/passwd' and nuke your system.

Comment: I already edit the answers I think It is better formulated

Comment: You mean, you edited the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok first of all.. If some parameter is an array, then calling it $results would be more logic then $result. Also, why `echo "<input name=\"" . $somearray['name'] . "\">";` if you can simply `echo '<input name="' . $somearray['name'] . '">';`

If there isn't any function or special reason to add the buffer here: `$identifier = $array['name_file'];`, then your problem might be, that you don't end the `$identifier` with `unset();`. So my first guess would be this:

```
foreach ($result as $array){
    $identifier = $array['name_file'];
    echo  '<input type="hidden" id="id_file"   value="' . $array['id_file'].  '\">';
    echo $array['name_file'] . '<a id="' . urlencode($identifier) . '\" href="#" class="delete" >Delete</a><br/>';
    unset($identifier);
}
```

Because `foreach` generated "$array", will be unset automatically when new entry gets loaded, but `$identifier` doesn't. That's why you need `unset()` to reset the value for the next entry.

However much more easier would be to remove the $identifier altogether:

```
foreach ($result as $array){
    echo  '<input type="hidden" id="id_file"   value="' . $array['id_file'].  '\">';
    echo $array['name_file'] . '<a id="' . urlencode($array['name_file']) . '\" href="#" class="delete" >Delete</a><br/>';
}
```

There are some other points in your code that I would pick on, but this should basically solve the problem.

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, I created these scripts. *Its basically programming for free :)*
As you understand, you must add your custom db classes and such to it yourself. But since they appear to be simple array. Then this should do the trick:

```
include '../Model/File.php';
$objFile = new File();
$files_array = $objFile->listFiles();
```

First some notes..

> I cant find any reason for this.. $directory = dir($path);
>
> Why are the types here? Your script doesnt seem to deal with uploads..
>   $types = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'txt', 'gif', 'png', 'doc', 'docx',
>   'pdf', 'xlsx', 'pptx');
>
> Why is this here? If you have some other variable above your provided
>   code, then unset($identifier); $identifier = "";
>
> Since we have an example array above, we have commented this part out
>   $objFile = new File(); $result = $objFile->listFiles();

Live example: **http://kopli.pri.ee/stackoverflow/6986586.php**

Note, that I don't have the files.. So the example is how the general table is being displayed and also the jQuery effect.

**Main file**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Kalle rocks!</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <style>
        table {width: 600px; margin: 0px auto;}
        th, td {padding: 5px;}
        th {border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
        .tfoot {background: #EAEAEA;}
        .delete {background: #FFCECE; color: black; cursor: pointer; text-align: center;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php

// Where the files sit
$path = 'uploadedfiles/';

// Example array
$files_array[] = array(
    'id_archivo' => 41,
    'nombre_archivo' => '1294861647_-desktop.png',
    'fecha' => '2011-08-08 15:10:09'
);
$files_array[] = array(
    'id_archivo' => 42,
    'nombre_archivo' => 'Dragon_Ball_Simpsons.jpg',
    'fecha' => '2011-08-08 15:11:49 '
);
$files_array[] = array(
    'id_archivo' => 43,
    'nombre_archivo' => 'VATOS.jpg ',
    'fecha' => '2011-08-08 16:30:00'
);

// Start the table       
echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>';

// Run the foreach loop
$files_displayed = 0;
foreach ($files_array as $fileid => $file){
    $files_displayed++;
    echo '<tr id="fileid_' . $fileid . '">
        <td>' . $fileid . '</td>
        <td>' . $file['nombre_archivo'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $file['fecha'] . '</td>
        <td class="delete"><span>[X]</span></td>
    </tr>';
}

// End the table and display totals
echo '</body>
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="tfoot">Currently displaying ' . $files_displayed . ' files total</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>';

?>
<script>
$('.delete').click(function () {
    var file_row = $(this).parent('tr');
    var fileid = file_row.attr('id').replace('fileid_', '');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'ajax_file_delete.php',
        data: 'action=delete&fileid=' + fileid,
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        success: function() {
            file_row.fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Ajax file** (ajax_file_delete.php)

```
<?php

$path = 'uploadedfiles/';

// In theory, your include '../Model/File.php'; and $result= $objFile->listFiles(); should be included here, so the array would be imported

$files_array[] = array(
    'id_archivo' => 41,
    'nombre_archivo' => '1294861647_-desktop.png',
    'fecha' => '2011-08-08 15:10:09'
);
$files_array[] = array(
    'id_archivo' => 42,
    'nombre_archivo' => 'Dragon_Ball_Simpsons.jpg',
    'fecha' => '2011-08-08 15:11:49 '
);
$files_array[] = array(
    'id_archivo' => 43,
    'nombre_archivo' => 'VATOS.jpg ',
    'fecha' => '2011-08-08 16:30:00'
);

if ($_GET['delete']) {
    unlink($path . $files_array[$_GET['fileid']]['nombre_archivo']);
    // also, you can add here some mysql related stuff to delete the file from the db
}

?>
```

Comment: I already edit but I want to know what would be your approach, I mean first take the id to delete from db, then delete the file from the directory

Comment: Ok basically I would use ajax. How do you want to delete the file -- via php only or with ajax? Because, currently it seems, that you are planning to use jquery for that..based on `<a href="#">`. You mentioned db, but there seems to be no db.. Did you mean simply the folder where files are or you have some mysql or similar db? As far as I understand, you want to make a simply file viewer -- get files from a folder and delete them from a link? What features does ../Model/File.php have?

Comment: ajax with mootools , I have mysql , file has displayfiles, store files in db and directory, delete files

Comment: I'm not familiar with mootools. Can you include an example array of $result = $objFile->listFiles(); in the form of php, so I can simply copy it for my example?

Comment: ok, I dont know what you mean by an example, I already edit the post, I only using the kind of save the filename in the db, and the file in the directory server, and I wanna know if there other ways of doing it with ajax

Comment: Well, the $result is an array, that is produced with $objFile->listFiles();. I cannot see all your files, so basically you need to tell us, what array does it produce echo '<pre>' print_r($result); echo '</pre>'; And copy that to your question too.

Comment: I edited my answer. This is my approach. Obviously you must setup for your own need, but should get the general idea from this.

Answer (score 1):

In my honest opinion in these things I think you should use `$directory` at least one. Probably here: `$result= $objFile->listFiles($directory);`.

Try var dumping `$results`.